# handling concurrent requests and race conditions is rails using redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, concurrency, race-condition

I am building an application with ruby on rails as a part of a hiring process. This is my first time using ruby or rails. 
It's required to handle concurrent requests while saving to DB i.e.: if the server is hosted on many machines and they sent requests simultaneously it should be correctly ordered. I thought to use Redis as a queue to store requests and handle them one by one, but unfortunately, I did not find enough resources or tutorials on how to implement that. 
Can someone explains how this is implemented or show me a better way to achieve the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few guides online and questions asking this question already, but as you're a fellow Egyptian:

I'd suggest reading https://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2020/06/07/race-conditions-on-rails/. TL:DR: lock the row of the record you're dealing with in the database (and any related records) so they can't be touched while the first thread is doing its thing:

```
def charge_user_for_order(user_id, order_id)
  user = User.find(user_id)
  order = Order.find(order_id)
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    user.lock! # locks the user record so other threads can't modify it until the transaction is done
    user.credits -= order.price
    user.save!
    order.paid!
  end
end
```

Comment: I think your approach is valid only for threads concurrency, but it will not work with distributed servers

Comment: If you need to process in order across all servers based on time you can add each request to a Redis Stream (https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/Redis/pconnect/php-redis-pconnect-method-examples.html). This will ensure that they are in order chronologically as streams sets a message ID based off of a time stamp in MS with an incremented tie breaker at the end.  Have another process that pulls items off of the stream and writes to the database.